# XMLParser iOS Swift - How to check if post is new

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, parsing, nsxmlparser

I have a working project to parse XML data from an .rss file. I am able to refresh the tableview (pull to refresh) and display the new data (if available).

I want to know how to let the user know if the post is new, so it never has been in the tableview before. I need this to send the user an push message (check every 15 minutes) with the new Title and Description (if available).

The project is basicly about a police/ambulance monitoring.

[Click here to see what the app looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/symU1.png)

Thanks for helping me :).

My code to parse the XML file:

```
func getDataTableViewRss(){
    let url:NSURL = NSURL(string: "http://semmikabel.nl/feed.rss")!
    parser = XMLParser(contentsOf: url as URL)!
    parser.delegate = self
    parser.parse()
    self.tabBarController?.tabBar.items?[0].badgeValue = String(describing: self.blogPosts.count)
}
```

This is my code to parse the data:

```
func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, didStartElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?, attributes attributeDict: [String : String]) {
    eName = elementName
    if elementName == "item" {
        postTitle = String()
        postDescription = String()
        postDatePosted = String()
    }

}

func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, foundCharacters string: String) {
    let data = string.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines)
    if (!data.isEmpty) {
        if eName == "description" {
            postTitle += data
        } else if eName == "title" {
            postDescription += data
        } else if eName == "link" {
            postLink += data
        } else if eName == "pubDate" {
            //postDatePosted += data

            let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
            dateFormatter.dateFormat = "EEE, dd LLL yyyy HH:mm:ss Z"
            dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en-us")
            dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "GMT")
            let fd = dateFormatter.date(from: data)

            if let fd = fd  {
                let formatStr = DateFormatter.dateFormat(fromTemplate: "E d MMM HH:mm", options: 0, locale: Locale.current)
                dateFormatter.dateFormat = formatStr
                postDatePosted += dateFormatter.string(from: fd)
            }

        }
    }
}



func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, didEndElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?) {
    if elementName == "item" {
        let blogPost: BlogPost = BlogPost()

        blogPost.postTitle = postTitle
        blogPost.postDescription = postDescription
        blogPost.postLink = postLink
        savedTitle = blogPost.postTitle
        blogPost.postDatePosted = postDatePosted
        blogPosts.append(blogPost)
        //print(blogPost.postTitle)

    }
}
```

Code to put each row into an tableview:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell") as! TableViewCell

    let blogPost: BlogPost = blogPosts[indexPath.row]
    cell.lblOne?.text = blogPost.postTitle
    cell.lblTwo?.text = blogPost.postDescription
    cell.txtTimeDate?.text = blogPost.postDatePosted

    return cell
}
```